# Using SQL to build a spreadsheet with dynamic column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and self taught on what I currently know. Is it possible to setup a set of dynamic column headers? For example below I have in a spreadsheet Columns A-E from one data table (pic704current) and what I'm trying to do is recreate F-O which is part of a secondary table (Cataloginfo.catalog, based on Cataloginfo.mediaid='

Also, I need to do it this way because the catalogs change frequently and entering them manually defeats the purpose of automating this report.

UPDATE: I've updated the code to reflect what I've been messing around with. Obviously there are a few parts I have commented out that I need to work on later but so far I'm still having issues getting this to even run. I appreciate the help and push in the right direction!

I'm looking for idea's on how to do this or if it's even possible in SQL. Any other details or clarification just let me know. THANKS!

[image]

```
SELECT a.ARTICLE
,a.ARTICLENAME
,a.RD
,a.SFC
,a.ITEMMERCH as Merch
,a.Offer
,a.WPFROM

--,CASE WHEN THEN "Yes" else "no" END AS [Unbuilt]
--,Case when b.Brand = 'Seventh Avenue' then b.catalog 

FROM Lago_CID_Master a INNER JOIN CatalogInfo b ON (a.Offer = b.Catalog) AND (a.OfferYear = b.MailYear) JOIN PIC704Current c ON (a.Offer = c.CatID) and (a.OfferYear = c.year)


PIVOT  
(
    Lago_CID_Master.wpfrom(cataloginfo.catalog)  
FOR   
[cataloginfo.catalog]   
    IN (cataloginfo.mediaid('cat catalog'))
 AS q  )


WHERE b.Brand= 'Seventh Avenue' 
--and b.mediaid = ('CAT Catalog') 
and a.year=2020 
and b.seasonid = 'F20'
--ORDER by a.ARTICLE;
```

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: Oh Sorry, MS SQL Server @alexherm

Comment: I've done this sort of thing in Oracle using SQL Plus and SPOOL command.  I am not sure how it could be achieved in SQL Server.  I would attempt an approach where the dynamic header names are selected into row 1 with the rest of the data underneath.  Then export the data with no headers so that data row 1 automatically becomes the header.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like below. I did not test this as I have no data to work with. Add some data to work with to modify query.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT *
                               FROM (SELECT a.packnum,
                                            a.Description,
                                            a.RD,
                                            a.SFC,
                                            a.TwoDigitMerchCode as Merch
                                       FROM PIC704Current a 
                                      INNER JOIN CatalogInfo b 
                                         ON a.CatID = b.Catalog 
                                        AND a.Year = b.MailYear)
                              WHERE b.Brand = ''Seventh Avenue'' 
                                AND b.MediaId = ''cat catalog'' 
                                AND a.[year] = 2020 
                                AND b.seasonid = ''F20'') A
 PIVOT (max([Value]) FOR [mediaid] IN (' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(mediaid) FROM (SELECT mediaid FROM Cataloginfo ORDER BY mediaid) A FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ') ) p'

PRINT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL);
```